# Error tokenizing data when appending a CSV after dataframe plotting

Tags: dataframe, csv, append

After running a neural network, I put its data into a CSV. In order to plot the CSV, I convert it to a data frame and plot using `df.pivot_table.plot()` function. I am trying to run the neural network again with different parameters and append its data to the original CSV.

Here is the code I used to append the CSV:

```
with open(NameOfFile, mode = 'a') as csv_append:

    column_name = ['Layers', 'Dropout Layers', 'Dropout %', 'First Hidden Layer', 'Last Hidden Layer', 'Epoch', 'Batch', 'Loss', 'Network Max Loss', 'Network Min Loss']

    diction_append = DictWriter(csv_append, fieldnames = column_name)

    for loss,e,b in zip(losses, e_list, batch_list):
        diction_append.writerow({'Layers': model.layer_num, 'Dropout Layers':  model.dropout_layers, 'Dropout %': int(model.dropout_pct*100), 'First Hidden Layer' : model.h_first, 'Last Hidden Layer' : model.h_last, 'Epoch' : e+1, 'Batch' : b+1,'Loss' : loss, 'Network Max Loss' : maxim,  'Network Min Loss' :minim})

    csv_append.close()

    pd.read_csv(NameOfFile)
```

I convert the CSV to a data frame and plot here:

```
df = pd.read_csv(NameOfFile)

print(df)

df.head(n = 9)

df1 = df.groupby(['Layers','Epoch', 'Dropout %'], as_index = False)['Loss'].mean()

df1.pivot_table(index = 'Epoch', columns = ['Layers', 'Dropout %'], values = 'Loss').plot(kind = 'bar')
```

When I run the neural network and try to append again, I get this error message:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2

Can someone explain why this happens and any ways I can append the CSV?